want to append serviceId in FlexiCategory url in this jolt spec
This is the input:
[
  {
    "encryption-secret-key": "EPSP#2503Database"
  },
  {
    "resultStatus": {
      "status": "Success"
    },
    "productId": "P10016",
    "isRecordPresent": false,
    "bpId": "680010330",
    "customerId": "3080001364",
    "serviceId": "9892737030",
    "statusCode": ""
  },
  {
    "timer": "30",
    "isChat": "false",
    "mobile-number": "s5w_Y2kgTCmReOequa5HmQ==",
    "x-platform": "web",
    "clientInteractionId": "242142"
  }
]

This is desired output
[
  {
    "popupTitle": {
      "advanceTimer": {
        "timeInSec": "30",
        "type": "decreasing"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "popupContent": {
      "form": {
        "maxHeight": "400px",
        "formId": "acwCreate",
        "inputs": [
          {
            "formDropDown": {
              "title": "Ticket Type*",
              "id": "ticketType",
              "type": "Bottom_Sheet",
              "content": [
                {
                  "id": "SR",
                  "title": "Service Request"
                },
                {
                  "title": "Interaction Request",
                  "id": "IR"
                }
              ],
              "helperText": {
                "title": "Warning Text",
                "icon": "IcWarningColored"
              },
              "initialValue": {
                "ticketType": "IR"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "formDropDown": {
              "type": "Bottom_Sheet",
              "helperText": {
                "title": "Warning Text",
                "icon": "IcWarningColored"
              },
              "dependsOn": "formDropDown.ticketType",
              "title": "Type*",
              "id": "category",
              "initialValue": {
                "category": " "
              },
              "action": {
                "get": "/epsp-pattern/attribute/mobility-digialApi-acwCategory?productId=P10016&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "formDropDown": {
              "type": "Bottom_Sheet",
              "helperText": {
                "title": "Warning Text",
                "icon": "IcWarningColored"
              },
              "dependsOn": [
                "formDropDown.ticketType",
                "formDropDown.category"
              ],
              "initialValue": {
                "subcategory": " "
              },
              "title": "Sub Type*",
              "id": "subcategory",
              "action": {
                "get": "/epsp-pattern/attribute/mobility-digialApi-acwSubCategory?categoryId=^{formDropDown.category}$&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "formDropDown": {
              "type": "Bottom_Sheet",
              "helperText": {
                "title": "Warning Text",
                "icon": "IcWarningColored"
              },
              "dependsOn": [
                "formDropDown.ticketType",
                "formDropDown.subcategory"
              ],
              "initialValue": {
                "subsubcategory": " "
              },
              "title": "Sub Sub Type*",
              "id": "subsubcategory",
              "action": {
                "get": "/epsp-pattern/attribute/mobility-digialApi-acwSubSubCategory?subCategoryId=^{formDropDown.subcategory}$&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "apiContainer": {
              "dependsOn": [
                "formDropDown.ticketType",
                "formDropDown.category",
                "formDropDown.subcategory",
                "formDropDown.subsubcategory"
              ],
              "schemaType": "RAWDATA",
              "action": {
                "get": "/epsp-pattern/attribute/mobility-digialApi-acwFlexiCategory?type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$&categoryId=^{formDropDown.category}$&subSubCategoryId=^{formDropDown.subsubcategory}$&"serviceId=9892737030
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "submitAction": {
          "title": "Submit",
          "type": "FILL",
          "dependsOn": "formDropDown.subsubcategory",
          "action": {
            "post": "/epsp-pattern/interactions/acw-ticketcreate/app-mobility-interactions-acwcreate?type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$",
            "body": {
              "serviceId": "9892737030",
              "productId": "P10016",
              "customerId": "3080001364",
              "bpId": "680010330",
              "isChat": "false",
              "clientInteractionId": "242142"
            }
          },
          "disabled": true
        },
        "shouldAutoSubmit": true
      }
    }
  }
]

This is the humongous jolt which I am not able to map
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#chat.interaction.tab": "chat.margin.content[1].form.dependsOn",
      "#false": "ischat1",
      "#20": [
        "margin.marginAll",
        "chat.margin.marginAll"
      ],
      "#400px": [
        "popupContent.form.maxHeight",
        "chat.popupContent.form.maxHeight"
      ],
      "#30": [
        "margin.content[0].advanceTimer.timeInSec",
        "popupTitle.advanceTimer.timeInSec"
      ],
      "#decreasing": [
        "margin.content[0].advanceTimer.type",
        "popupTitle.advanceTimer.type"
      ],
      "#acwCreate": [
        "margin.content[1].form.formId",
        "popupContent.form.formId",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.formId",
        "chat.popupContent.form.formId"
      ],
      "#Ticket Type": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.title"
      ],
      "#ticketType": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.id",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.id"
      ],
      "#acwCreateChatTicketType": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.id",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.id"
      ],
      "#Bottom_Sheet": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.type",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.type",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.type",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.type",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.type",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.type",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.type",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.type",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.type",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.type",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.type",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.type",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.type",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.type",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.type",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.type"
      ],
      "#SR": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[0].id",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[0].id",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[0].id",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[0].id"
      ],
      "#Service Request": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[0].title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[0].title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[0].title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[0].title"
      ],
      "#Interaction Request": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[1].title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[1].title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[1].title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[1].title"
      ],
      "#Warning Text": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.helperText.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.helperText.title"
      ],
      "#IcWarningColored": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.helperText.icon",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.helperText.icon"
      ],
      "#formDropDown.ticketType": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]"
      ],
      "#formDropDown.acwCreateChatTicketType": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]"
      ],
      "#Type": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.title"
      ],
      "#category": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.id",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.id"
      ],
      "#acwCreateChatCategory": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.id",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.id"
      ],
      "# ": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.initialValue.category",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.initialValue.subcategory",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.initialValue.subsubcategory",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.initialValue.category",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.initialValue.subcategory",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.initialValue.subsubcategory",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.initialValue.acwCreateChatCategory",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.initialValue.acwCreateChatSubcategory",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.initialValue.acwCreateChatSubsubcategory",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.initialValue.acwCreateChatCategory",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.initialValue.acwCreateChatSubcategory",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.initialValue.acwCreateChatSubsubcategory"
      ],
      "#IR": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[1].id",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.initialValue.ticketType",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[1].id",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.initialValue.ticketType",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[1].id",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[0].formDropDown.initialValue.acwCreateChatTicketType",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.content[1].id",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[0].formDropDown.initialValue.acwCreateChatTicketType"
      ],
      "#/epsp-pattern/attribute/mobility-digialApi-acwCategory?productId=P10016": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.action.get",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.action.get",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[1].formDropDown.action.get",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[1].formDropDown.action.get"
      ],
      "#formDropDown.category": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]"
      ],
      "#formDropDown.acwCreateChatCategory": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]"
      ],
      "#Sub Type": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.title"
      ],
      "#subcategory": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.id",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.id"
      ],
      "#acwCreateChatSubcategory": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.id",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.id"
      ],
      "#/epsp-pattern/attribute/mobility-digialApi-acwSubCategory?categoryId=": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.action.get",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.action.get",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[2].formDropDown.action.get",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[2].formDropDown.action.get"
      ],
      "#formDropDown.subcategory": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]"
      ],
      "#formDropDown.acwCreateChatSubcategory": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.dependsOn",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]"
      ],
      "#Sub Sub Type": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.title",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.title"
      ],
      "#subsubcategory": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.id",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.id"
      ],
      "#acwCreateChatSubsubcategory": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.id",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.id"
      ],
      "#/epsp-pattern/attribute/mobility-digialApi-acwSubSubCategory?subCategoryId=": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.action.get",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.action.get",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[3].formDropDown.action.get",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[3].formDropDown.action.get"
      ],
      "#RAWDATA": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.schemaType",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.schemaType",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.schemaType",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.schemaType"
      ],
      "#/epsp-pattern/attribute/mobility-digialApi-acwFlexiCategory?type=": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.action.get",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.action.get",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.action.get",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.action.get"
      ],
      "#Submit": [
        "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.title",
        "popupContent.form.submitAction.title",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.title",
        "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.title"
      ],
      "#FILL": [
        "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.type",
        "popupContent.form.submitAction.type",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.type",
        "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.type"
      ],
      "#formDropDown.subsubcategory": [
        "margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "popupContent.form.submitAction.dependsOn"
      ],
      "#formDropDown.acwCreateChatSubsubcategory": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "chat.popupContent.form.inputs[4].apiContainer.dependsOn[]",
        "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.dependsOn"
      ],
      "#/epsp-pattern/interactions/acw-ticketcreate/app-mobility-interactions-acwcreate": [
        "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.post",
        "popupContent.form.submitAction.action.post",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.post",
        "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.action.post"
      ],
      "#acw.subsubcategory": [
        "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.dependsOn"
      ],
      "#acw.acwCreateChatSubsubcategory": [
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.dependsOn"
      ],
      "#true": [
        "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.disabled",
        "popupContent.form.submitAction.disabled",
        "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.disabled",
        "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.disabled",
        "popupContent.form.shouldAutoSubmit"
      ],
      "*": {
        "x-platform": "x-platform",
        "isChat": [
          "isChat",
          "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.isChat",
          "popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.isChat",
          "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.isChat",
          "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.isChat"
        ],
        "isRecordPresent": "isRecordPresent",
        "statusCode": "statusCode",
        "serviceId": [
          "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.serviceId",
          "popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.serviceId",
          "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.serviceId",
          "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.serviceId"
        ],
        "productId": [
          "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.productId",
          "popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.productId",
          "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.productId",
          "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.productId"
        ],
        "customerId": [
          "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.customerId",
          "popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.customerId",
          "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.customerId",
          "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.customerId"
        ],
        "bpId": [
          "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.bpId",
          "popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.bpId",
          "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.bpId",
          "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.bpId"
        ],
        "clientInteractionId": [
          "margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.clientInteractionId",
          "popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.clientInteractionId",
          "chat.margin.content[1].form.submitAction.action.body.clientInteractionId",
          "chat.popupContent.form.submitAction.action.body.clientInteractionId"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "margin": {
        "content": {
          "[1]": {
            "form": {
              "submitAction": {
                "action": {
                  "post": "=concat(@(1,post),'?type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$')"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "popupContent": {
        "form": {
          "submitAction": {
            "action": {
              "post": "=concat(@(1,post),'?type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$')"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "margin": {
        "content": {
          "[1]": {
            "form": {
              "inputs": {
                "[1]": {
                  "formDropDown": {
                    "action": {
                      "get": "=concat(@(1,get),'&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$')"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "margin": {
        "content": {
          "[1]": {
            "form": {
              "inputs": {
                "[2]": {
                  "formDropDown": {
                    "action": {
                      "get": "=concat(@(1,get),'^{formDropDown.category}$&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$')"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "margin": {
        "content": {
          "[1]": {
            "form": {
              "inputs": {
                "[3]": {
                  "formDropDown": {
                    "action": {
                      "get": "=concat(@(1,get),'^{formDropDown.subcategory}$&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$')"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "margin": {
        "content": {
          "[1]": {
            "form": {
              "inputs": {
                "[4]": {
                  "apiContainer": {
                    "action": {
                      "get": "=concat(@(1,get),'^{formDropDown.ticketType}$&categoryId=^{formDropDown.category}$&subSubCategoryId=^{formDropDown.subsubcategory}$')"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "popupContent": {
        "form": {
          "inputs": {
            "[1]": {
              "formDropDown": {
                "action": {
                  "get": "=concat(@(1,get),'&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$')"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "popupContent": {
        "form": {
          "inputs": {
            "[2]": {
              "formDropDown": {
                "action": {
                  "get": "=concat(@(1,get),'^{formDropDown.category}$&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$')"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "popupContent": {
        "form": {
          "inputs": {
            "[3]": {
              "formDropDown": {
                "action": {
                  "get": "=concat(@(1,get),'^{formDropDown.subcategory}$&type=^{formDropDown.ticketType}$')"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "popup## Heading ##Content": {
        "form": {
          "inputs": {
            "[4]": {
              "apiContainer": {
                "action": {
                  "get": "=concat(@(1,get),'^{formDropDown.ticketType}$&categoryId=^{formDropDown.category}$&subSubCategoryId=^{formDropDown.subsubcategory}$')"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": "[].&",
      "margin": "[].&",
      "popupTitle": "[].&",
      "popupContent": "[].&"
    }
  }
]        

serviceId should be appended in flexiCategory Url
